# How to prevent IBM MobileFirst JSONStore from being backup to iCloud or iTunes?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, icloud, itunes

I'm building a hybrid iOS app using IBM MobileFirst.

Questions:

1) How to prevent IBM MobileFirst JSONStore from being backup to iCloud or iTunes?
Do we need to use NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey to exclude the JSONStore path?

2) Is yes, Where is the JSONStore Path located in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` API in order to prevent JSONStore data from being backup to iCloud or iTunes.

JSONStore Data is stored under following path :
`<App Id>/Documents/wljsonstore/jsonstore.sqlite`

Comment: thx for relying...should I hardcode the path? How can i get the app id?